# transform SQL query to rails query with many to many relations, what is the best practice?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Hi this is my data model:

[image]

and I want to transform this query to the activeRecord API

```
select c.id, c.name, c.phone, c.created_at,c.updated_at,s.status
from contacts c,contacts_lists cl, contactstatuses s
where cl.list_id = ? and s.company_id = ? and c.id = cl.contact_id and c.id = s.contact_id
```

What would be the best way to do that? .... also what is the best practice here?, run the sql plain or use the activeRecord API

Comment: Might want to investigate a creating a view and basing a model on it.

Comment: thanks for the idea, I willl to analyze the  frencuency with which this query will be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use joins to join together all the tables you need.
I asume you have set all the relations in your models and that your models are named Contact, Contactstatus and ContactList.
Then you should be able to build a query like this one:

```sql
select c.id, c.name, c.phone, c.created_at, c.updated_at, s.status
from contacts c
JOINS contacts_lists cl ON cl.contact_id = c.id
JOINS contactstatuses s ON s.contact_id = c.id
where cl.list_id = ? 
  and s.company_id = ?;
```

With the following code:

```rb
# I filled the id values (questionmarks) with a 1
Contact.select(:id, :name, :phone, :created_at, :updated_at, Contactstatus.arel_table[:status]).joins(:contacts_lists, :contactstatuses).where(contacts_lists: { list_id: 1 }, contactstatuses: { company_id: 1 })
```

Comment: thank you!, but the result is not carrying the status field, I think this part is not working Contactstatus.arel_table[:status], if a I run this: Contact.select(:id, Contactstatus.arel_table[:status]).joins(:contacts_lists, :contactstatuses).where(contacts_lists: { list_id: 1 }, contactstatuses: { company_id: 1 }), I got :  #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Contact id: 3>, #<Contact id: 1>, #<Contact id: 2>]>

Comment: You do not see it in your ActiveRecord::Relation output but please try adding .first.status. It should be there. It is not part of the Contact model that's why it won't show up in your ActiveRecord::Relation output.